# Flask Jinja tempate loop: error not showing

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3, flask, jinja2

I am trying to run a googlemaps API map, only when there are GPS values available.

This checks if there are GPS, if not then error1:

```
error1 = None
GPS =[]
try:
    GPS = gd.get_gps(request.form['address'])
    if len(GPS) == 0:
        error1 = 'No GPS data'
    else:
        GPS.append(GPS)
except:
    error1 ='No GPS data'
    pass
return render_template('Client_Details.html', error1 =error1,GPS=GPS)
```

this is the template:

```
{% if error1 %}
<p class='alert'>{{ error1 }}</p>
{% elif GPS %}
<div id = "location">
<caption> Location <caption>
{{googlemap("map_name", lat=GPS[0], lng= GPS[1], zoom=17, maptype= 'SATELLITE', markers=[(GPS[0], GPS[1])])}}
{% endif %}
```

This works if there are GPS available and the map shows, but if there are no GPS (ie GPS list is empty), it is not showing `error1`, but giving me this error:

```
AttributeError: lat and lng required
```

Comment: can you print the {{error1}} in your template, when there are no GPS?

Comment: this is my problem - if there are no GPS, then it should print {{error1}}  ('No GPS data'), but instead it is still trying to run the googlemap...

Comment: it is to print {{error1}} out of your if condition, just check what it is in side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are recycling the `GPS` variable in a strange way, try to avoid that.

```
error1 = None
GPS = []

try:
    form_coordinates = gd.get_gps(request.form['address'])
    if not form_coordinates:
        error1 = 'No GPS data'
    else:
        GPS.append(form_coordinates)
except:
    error1 = 'No GPS data'

return render_template('Client_Details.html', error1=error1, GPS=GPS)
```

Also, use the jinja2 [`length`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#length) function to check if there are any coordinates.

```
{% if GPS is defined and GPS|length > 0 %}
<div id="location">
<caption> Location </caption>
{{googlemap("map_name", lat=GPS[0], lng=GPS[1], zoom=17, maptype='SATELLITE', markers=[(GPS[0], GPS[1])])}}
</div>
{% else %}
<p class='alert'>{{ error1 }}</p>
{% endif %}
```